# Не работает редирект на страницу, при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript

```js
function fun1() {
  window.location.href = "Dino.html";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.hipwallpaper.com/i/93/78/onIlzr.jpg" alt="Snow">
  <button onclick="fun1" class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В **инлайн** обработчиках находится выполняемый. Для того, чтобы функция выполнилась, нужно, чтобы он была вызвана.

Поэтому для решения достаточно дописать `()`

```js
function fun1() {
  window.location.href = "Dino.html";
}
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.hipwallpaper.com/i/93/78/onIlzr.jpg" alt="Snow">
  <button onclick="fun1()" class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

Либо использовать не инлайновые обработчики, а метод [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
function fun1() {
  window.location.href = "Dino.html";
}

document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', fun1);
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.hipwallpaper.com/i/93/78/onIlzr.jpg" alt="Snow">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```